# Локальный сайт в глобальный

Tags: php, openserver

Имеется сайт на php в open server, работает локально. Как можно сделать его глобальным?

Comment: 1) перенести на какой-нибудь хостинг 2) получить внешний ip, зарегать домен, открыть опенсервер наружу

Comment: По-хорошему находишь платный хостинг и туда как и на опенсервер все размещаешь.